# copy! and slicing in Julia

Tags: performance, julia

I was implementing Merge Sort in Julia as an exercise and noticed there is slight difference in performance and memory allocation when I use **copy!** and traditional value assignment by **slicing** (commented bit). Could someone explain what this difference stems from?

My merge function in MergeSort

```
function myMerge(left, right)
    l = 1
    r = 1
    k = length(left) + length(right)
    result = zeros(k)
    for i in 1:k
        if left[l] <= right[r]
            result[i] = left[l]
            l += 1
            if l > length(left)
                #result[i+1:end] = right[r:end] # <-------- this is slower and uses more memory
                copy!(result, i+1, right, r)  # <-------- this is faster
                return result
            end
        else
            result[i] = right[r]
            r += 1
            if r > length(right)
                #result[i+1:end] = left[l:end]# <-------- this is slower and uses more memory 
                copy!(result, i+1, left, l)  #   <-------- this is faster
                return result
            end
        end
    end
    return result
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  `right[r:end]` is allocating, because a slice creates a copy.  You can use a view instead:

```
result[i+1:end] .= @view right[r:end]
```

Speaking in terms of micro-optimizations, `copy!` (did you actually mean `copyto!`, BTW?) could still be a just a bit better, since while creating a view works in constant time/space, there's nevertheless a small overhead that might not be elided.

Comment: The compiler can sometimes elide the allocation of views if it can prove that they don't escape the current context. If it can not, they often appear as many small allocations. Getting rid of them can actually increase performance quite a lot in performance sensitive code.